# No funciona la librería SweetAlert con PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

Tengo mi archivo PHP llamado validatecredentials.php. Básicamente es un inicio de sesión, lo que quiero hacer es que si el usuario inició sesión correctamente, se muestre un SweetAlert con un mensaje de éxito, y que si el usuario no lo ha hecho correctamente, se muestre un SweetAlert con un mensaje de fracaso. Pero no lo he podido hacer funcionar.

Este es mi código PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$contra = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contra', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


// Importar SweetAlert2
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');

//Crear la conexion SQL
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
 die("Conexión fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT password FROM webcustomers WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $hashedPassword);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

if (password_verify($contra, $hashedPassword)) {
   // Si la contraseña ingresada es correcta, inicia sesión en la aplicación
   $hashedCookieEmail = hash("sha256", $email);
   $hashedCookiePass = hash("sha256", $hashedPassword);
   setcookie("emailUsuario", $hashedCookieEmail, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   setcookie("contraUsuario", $hashedCookiePass, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   ?>
   <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11" defer></script>
   <script>
       Swal.fire({ icon: "success", title: "Inicio de sesión exitoso", confirmButtonText: "Genial!" });
   </script>
   <?php
   return;
} else {
   // Si la contraseña ingresada es incorrecta, muestra un mensaje de error
   ?>
   <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11" defer></script>
   <script>
       Swal.fire({
           icon: 'error',
           title: 'Oops...',
           text: 'La contraseña es incorrecta'
       });
   </script>
   <?php
   return;
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

He intentado sacando esta línea y agregándola, pero no funciona:

```
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

Y cuando lo he sacado me aparece el siguiente error en consola:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined
    at validatecredentials.php:3:9
```

He intentado realizando una petición a AJAX, pero incluso de esta forma sigue sin funcionar. Mi código de Javascript es el siguiente:

```
// Captura el evento de envío del formulario de inicio de sesión
        document.querySelector('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            // Previene que se envíe el formulario por defecto
            event.preventDefault();

            // Obtiene los valores de los campos de correo electrónico y contraseña
            var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
            var contra = document.querySelector('#contra').value;

            // Crea un objeto FormData para enviar los datos del formulario mediante AJAX
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('email', email);
            formData.append('contra', contra);

            // Envía una petición AJAX al archivo PHP validatecredentials.php
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'validatecredentials.php');
            xhr.send(formData);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if (response.success) {
                        // Si el inicio de sesión fue exitoso, muestra un mensaje de éxito con SweetAlert
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Inicio de sesión exitoso',
                            text: 'Bienvenido a Strant Store'
                        });
                        // Redirige al usuario a la página tienda.php
                        window.location.href = 'https://strant.store/tienda.php';
                    } else {
                        // Si el inicio de sesión no fue exitoso, muestra un mensaje de error con SweetAlert
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Oops...',
                            text: response.error
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    // Si hubo un error en la petición, muestra un mensaje de error con SweetAlert
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: response.error
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar el SweetAlert, inserta las cookies en el navegador, pero no muestra los SweetAlert. Cabe destacar que mi PHP lo he modificado con las siguientes líneas de código para poder manejar la petición de AJAX

```
   $response = array('success' => true);
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola sweetalert2 es para JS tu lo estas poniendo en php prueba a ponerlo asi:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
   <script>
       const Swal = require('sweetalert2')
       Swal.fire({ icon: "success", title: "Inicio de sesión exitoso", confirmButtonText: "Genial!" });
   </script>
```

ELSE

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
   <script>
       const Swal = require('sweetalert2')
       Swal.fire({
           icon: 'error',
           title: 'Oops...',
           text: 'La contraseña es incorrecta'
       });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que estás intentando importar la biblioteca `SweetAlert2` en tu archivo PHP, lo cual no es posible, ya que `SweetAlert2` es una biblioteca de JavaScript y no de PHP.

En el archivo HTML donde llames a `validatecredentials.php` debe estar importada la librería:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Y con esto ya reconocerá el `Swall`. Entonces, en tu condición `if` y `else` debería quedar así:

```
if (password_verify($contra, $hashedPassword)) {
   // ...
   <script>
       Swal.fire({ icon: "success", title: "Inicio de sesión exitoso", confirmButtonText: "Genial!" });
   </script>
   <?php
   return;
} else {
   // ...
   <script>
       Swal.fire({
           icon: 'error',
           title: 'Oops...',
           text: 'La contraseña es incorrecta'
       });
   </script>
   <?php
   return;
}
```

Y no necesitarías usar:

```
// const Swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

Comment: Así lo he hecho, pero no ha funcionado. Lo puedes comprobar en el siguiente [enlace](https://strant.store/iniciarsesion.html). Puedes usar cualquier mail y cualquier contra.

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined at validatecredentials.php:3:8

Comment: Los importo en el HTML, al comienzo en el head con la linea `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Así mismo he intentado con AJAX, pero sigo sin hacerlo funcionar lamentablemente.

Comment: Intenta ponerlo al final... los scripts siempre van al final, justo antes del cierre del body... y borra `const Swal = require('sweetalert2');`

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo en consola el error de `Swal is not defined`, habiendo borrado el `const Swal = require('sweetalert2');` y habiendo puesto el script al final.

Comment: Y al ponerlo arriba de tu validación, tampoco?...

Comment: No, tampoco. No sé qué puede ser la verdad. Podría intentar con un simple alert predeterminado y ver si funciona

Comment: Vale me avisa, pero mas o menos por ahí va la idea...

Comment: Sí, sí funciona con los alerts predeterminados, el problema es con la librería.